# Selecting a value from multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, attributes

I have a little problem with my SQL sentence. I have a table with a product_id and a flag_id, now I want to get the product_id which matches all the flags specified. I know you have to inner join it self, to match more than one, but I don't know the exact SQL for it.

Table for flags

```
   product_id | flag_id
   1            1
   1            51
   1            23
   2            1
   2            51
   3            1
```

I would like to get all products which have flag_id 1, 51 and 23.

Comment: Hi @Ulrik, some sample tables or queries would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> get the product_id which ***matches all*** the flags specified

This problem is called [Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). One way to solve it, is to do this:

- `GROUP BY product_id` .
- Use the `IN` predicate to specify which flags to match.
- Use the `HAVING` clause to ensure the flags each product have,

like this:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM flags
WHERE flag_id IN(1, 51, 23)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT flag_id) = 3
```

The `HAVING` clause will ensure that the selected `product_id` must have both the three flags, if it has only one or two of them it will be eliminated.

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47ca3/2)

This will give you only:

```
| PRODUCT_ID |
--------------
|          1 |
```

Comment: just to clear something up, this would assume that `product_id` is _not_ the primary key?

Comment: @epoch - Yes, you are right. Sorry, the question was lack more details about the problem, but now he posted some sample data.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, this is awsome... Now I am having the issue that when I want the product_id 3 it returns all of them. How do a solve this? I have to create the SQL sentence dynamically.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle - This is because all of the three has this flag `1` to solve this use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`, something like `SELECT product_id
FROM flags
WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT product_id
                        FROM flags 
                        WHERE flag_id <> 1)` see it here in this [Updated demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47ca3/7)

Comment: @Mahmoud - I know, I tried to do this: SELECT product_id FROM products_attributes
WHERE attribute_id IN(17, 22, 21, 8) AND attribute_id NOT IN(13) GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 4, that didn't work, then it returned nothing and before et returned my two products

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle, Use `AND product_id NOT IN(SELECT product_id FROM products_attributes WHERE attribute_id = 13)` instead of `AND attribute_id NOT IN(13)`, like this: `SELECT product_id 
FROM products_attributes 
WHERE attribute_id IN(17, 22, 21, 8) 
  AND product_id NOT IN(SELECT product_id FROM products_attributes WHERE attribute_id = 13) 
GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 4`

Comment: I have some flags that have to be present and some that has to be not present.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle this way it should work fine, like in my previous comment, can you please modify this [sql fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47ca3/2) and show more data and show an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE flag_id IN(1,2,..);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for something else :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it would help if you can specify what you have tried before, but as I understood you need to get products with certain flags, so you can just use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT product_id FROM Product WHERE flag_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for something else :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME A INNER JOIN TABLE_NAME B ON A.product_id = B.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for something else :)